# Copying Files From Xcode With Command Line Tool

Tags: objective-c

I have am working on a Command Line Tool in Xcode.  The challenge that I am facing is the following:  If a file does not exist where I expect it to be, e.g. `/Path/To/The.File`, how can place a copy of `The.File` at `/Path/To/The.File` if it has been added to the project's resources?

With a MacOS application project, I believe I've used something similar to the following with success to get the file path:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"The" ofType:@"File"];
```

With the file path, I would then be able to execute code to copy the file from the file path to the expected location `/Path/To/The.File`.

Is it possible to accomplish this with a Command Line Tool in Xcode?

Comment: No. A command line tool is not a bundle. It cannot “contain” a file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to "embed" the resource `The.File` with the use of Makefile.

After building the project in Xcode, I placed the resource `The.File` into a temporary folder along with the compiled project `TheCompiledProject`.  Here are the contents of the Makefile:

```
UPDATE=bundledExecutable

BIN1=TheCompiledProject
BIN2=The.File

all: $(UPDATE)

$(UPDATE): ./$(BIN1) ./$(BIN2)
    @echo "UP  [ $@ ]"
    echo '#!/bin/bash' > $@
    echo 'FOLDER=`mktemp -d -t upgrade`' >> $@
    echo 'cd $$FOLDER; uudecode -c << '"'EOF' | tar -x" >> $@
    uuencode $(BIN1) $(BIN1) >> $@
    uuencode $(BIN2) $(BIN2) >> $@
    echo 'EOF' >> $@
    echo 'chmod a+x $$FOLDER/$(BIN1)' >> $@
    echo 'chmod a+x $$FOLDER/$(BIN2)' >> $@
    echo '$$FOLDER/$(BIN1)' >> $@
    echo 'rm -rf $$FOLDER' >> $@
    chmod a+x $@
```

If you use the `pathForResource` method, in `TheCompiledProject`, the filePath for `The.File` is returned as expected.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"The" ofType:@"File"];
```